# how to use javascript with imacros to read a file name

Tags: javascript, imacros

Is there a way i can use how to use javascript with imacros to read a file name? I know it is possible, but im just unable to find a result for the same.

My file name is

eg:
"title - keyword1 - keyword2.png"

I would like iMacros to help me read the title, keyword1 and keyword2 part alone from multiple files of the same way in a particular folder and give me the results.

Any help is much appreciated. thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a "loop version":

```
TAB T=1
SET myFolder D:/Temp/img/
SET urlFolder EVAL("{{!LOOP}} == 1 ? 'file:///{{myFolder}}' : 'javascript:undefined;';")
URL GOTO={{urlFolder}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TBODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET curFile EVAL("var f = []; var a = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/.+/g); for (i in a) {if (i % 4 == 0) f.push(a[i]);} f[{{!LOOP}} - 1];")
PROMPT {{curFile}}
```

---

You can start with my suggestion, for example:

```
SET myFolder D:/Temp/img/
URL GOTO=file:///{{myFolder}}
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO
TAG POS=1 TYPE=TBODY ATTR=* EXTRACT=TXT
SET files EVAL("var f = []; var a = '{{!EXTRACT}}'.match(/.+/g); for (i in a) {if (i % 4 == 0) f.push(a[i]);} JSON.stringify(f);")
PROMPT {{files}}
```

('iMacros for Firefox' macro)

Comment: hey thanks a lot buddy. this works, but it lists all the files at once. Would you be able to help me just list one file at a time? like using a loop operation. for every one loop, just one file needs to be listed?? thank you.. :)

Comment: Wonderful.. thanks a lot buddy... Your awesome... Now my one last query is.. how do I split the file name into 3 parts? My sample file name will be in this format: "how-are-you.png" so I want to be able to extract "how", "are", "you" into 3 separate variables... Many thanks again.. :)

Comment: Just use the `split()` function inside the `EVAL` command. Hope you can do it by yourself :)

Comment: hey i was able to do using the split command... thanks a lot again for the help buddy.. you rock... :)